# Como usar los radio buttons en react boostrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

Como puedo hacer para que los radio buttons queden seleccionados dependiendo del click que se le de a cada botón. Porque cuando le doy click en alguno de los dos radio buttons no se quedan seleccionados.

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    valuesQuestions: 1,
})

const handleChange = (event) => setState({
    ...state,
    valuesQuestions: event.currentTarget.value
});


<Form>
   <Form.Group className="mb-3">
    <Form.Label>¿Dolor de garganta?</Form.Label>
      <div className="btn-check selects--radio">
         </div>
           </Form.Group>
            <ToggleButtonGroup type="radio" name="options" value={state.valuesQuestions} default={1} onChange={handleChange}>
                        <ToggleButton value={1} variant="outline-warning" >Si</ToggleButton>
                        <ToggleButton value={2} variant="outline-warning"  >No</ToggleButton>
                    </ToggleButtonGroup>
                </Form>
```

Comment: no se si estás pasando bien los valores. <div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="flexRadioDefault1">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1">
    Default radio
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="flexRadioDefault2" checked>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault2">
    Default checked radio
  </label>
</div> en bootstrap sin usar styledComponents o mui, sería así.